# Краш приложения при вызове метода из другого класса через экземпляр

Tags: android, java

Привет.
Хочу вызвать метод из другого класса. Для это создаю экземпляр этого класса через конструктор с параметрами и вызываю метод через него.

```
DeviceUARTFragment PC = new DeviceUARTFragment(DeviceUARTFragment.DeviceUARTContext, DeviceUARTFragment.ftdid2xx);
```

Выяснил, что не инициализируется DeviceUARTContext в классе

Если присвою tempDevCount = 0 в методе createDeviceList, то работает.

Код класса, очищенный от всего лишнего:

```
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ftdi.j2xx.D2xxManager;
import com.ftdi.j2xx.FT_Device;

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment") public class DeviceUARTFragment extends Fragment{

    // original ///////////////////////////////
    static Context DeviceUARTContext;
    //D2xxManager ftdid2xx;
    static D2xxManager ftdid2xx;
    FT_Device ftDev = null;
    //public int DevCount = -1;
    public int DevCount = -1;
    int currentIndex = -1;
    int openIndex = 0;

    /*graphical objects*/
    EditText readText;
    EditText writeText;
    Spinner baudSpinner;;
    Spinner stopSpinner;
    Spinner dataSpinner;
    Spinner paritySpinner;
    Spinner flowSpinner;
    Spinner portSpinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> portAdapter;

    Button configButton;
    Button openButton;
    Button readEnButton;
    Button writeButton;
    static int iEnableReadFlag = 1;

    /*local variables*/
    int baudRate; /*baud rate*/
    byte stopBit; /*1:1stop bits, 2:2 stop bits*/
    byte dataBit; /*8:8bit, 7: 7bit*/
    byte parity;  /* 0: none, 1: odd, 2: even, 3: mark, 4: space*/
    byte flowControl; /*0:none, 1: flow control(CTS,RTS)*/
    int portNumber; /*port number*/
    ArrayList<CharSequence> portNumberList;

    public static final int readLength = 512;
    public int readcount = 0;
    public int iavailable = 0;
    byte[] readData;
    char[] readDataToText;
    public boolean bReadThreadGoing = false;
    public readThread read_thread;

    boolean uart_configured = false;

    // Empty Constructor
    public DeviceUARTFragment()
    {
    }

    /* Constructor */
    public DeviceUARTFragment(Context parentContext , D2xxManager ftdid2xxContext)
    {
        DeviceUARTContext = parentContext;
        ftdid2xx = ftdid2xxContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        createDeviceList();
    }

    public void createDeviceList()
    {
        //int tempDevCount = ftdid2xx.createDeviceInfoList(DeviceUARTContext);

        int tempDevCount = 0;

        //Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "|||||||||| tempDevCount" + tempDevCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (tempDevCount > 0)
        {
            if( DevCount != tempDevCount )
            {
                DevCount = tempDevCount;
                updatePortNumberSelector();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DevCount = -1;
            currentIndex = -1;
        }
    }

    public void updatePortNumberSelector()
    {
        //Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "updatePortNumberSelector:" + DevCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(DevCount == 2)
        {
            portAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(DeviceUARTContext, R.array.port_list_2,
                            R.layout.my_spinner_textview);
            portAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_textview);
            portSpinner.setAdapter(portAdapter);
            portAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "2 port device attached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //portSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnPortSelectedListener());
        }
        else if(DevCount == 4)
        {
            portAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(DeviceUARTContext, R.array.port_list_4,
                            R.layout.my_spinner_textview);
            portAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_textview);
            portSpinner.setAdapter(portAdapter);
            portAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "4 port device attached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //portSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnPortSelectedListener());
        }
        else
        {
            portAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(DeviceUARTContext, R.array.port_list_1,
                            R.layout.my_spinner_textview);
            portAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_textview);
            portSpinner.setAdapter(portAdapter);
            portAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "1 port device attached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //portSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnPortSelectedListener());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        DevCount = 0;

        createDeviceList();
        if(DevCount > 0)
        {
            connectFunction();
            SetConfig(baudRate, dataBit, stopBit, parity, flowControl);
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: Что-то кода маловато. Давайте ещё страниц пять, а то ничего не понять :-/

Comment: @olegall, хотя бы стектрейс ошибки приведите. И постарайтесь убрать из вопроса код, который не относится непосредственно к вопросу.

Comment: вы серьезно думаете, что кто-то захочет перебирать 300 строк вашего кода в поисках ошибки, когда вы даже не привели стактрейс??

Comment: извините, поправлю

Comment: привёл всё в порядок, вопрос актуален

Comment: повторю еще раз    
Если вы говорите про краш, обязателен к публикации стактрейс этого краша!!! И когда я пишу "обязателен", я не шучу, по тому что мой экстрасенс сегодня взял отгул, и я телепатически не могу определить, какое Эксцепшен вылетает, и на какой строчке...

Comment: "Выяснил, что не инициализируется DeviceUARTContext в классе" - а с какого перепугу он должен проинициализироваться?

"static Context DeviceUARTContext"
(DeviceUARTFragment.DeviceUARTContext)
Это что за шаманство? Контекст нигде не объявлен, так откуда он возьмется?

Понятно, что вылетает приложение, т.к. уже при первом запросе к переменной оно завалиться, примерно при объявлении portAdapter

Если вам нужен контекст фрагмента, то в конструкторе пишите DeviceUARTContext = this.getActivity(); или сразу передавайте контекст активити

Comment: @olegall, не стоит вот так прям сразу и игнорировать хинты и варнинги. Это про ваше `@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")`. Почитайте почему оно ругается. И сделайте правильно: через фабрику и `setArguments`.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, @SuppressLint("ValidFragment") там не нужен уже, этот линт нужен если у фрагмента не стандартный конструктор, но если добавить стандартный, как у него в коде, то линт можно убрать - не будет ворнингов или ошибок

Comment: @Nuclominus, угу и работать не будет (ну это если остальное исправить). речь не о линте, а о причинах этого подавления. типа подавил и ладно. надо стандартный конструктор - нате вам, а что работать не будет при рекреэйте фрагмента - не важно. Примерно такое же шаманство как со "static Context DeviceUARTContext". Правильная работа с фрагментами - через фабрику, не надо изобретать велосипед и избавляться от непонятных "вопросиков" не разобравшись.